# How vps instance like aws, google cloud,... scale with containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

As I understand. K8s will use the blueprint to create multiple containers on the same machine. But how this gonna help the scalability. For example, my laptop got 2 pods of backend servers and they got load balanced. I want to create another server because the cpu percentage got to high, but It is still on the same machine and it still does the same amount of work if not more, right? I really need a clear explaination to this problem, thank you.

Comment: If the resources if your machine are not sufficient you need another machine.

Comment: https://www.section.io/blog/scaling-horizontally-vs-vertically/